# Certificate chain validation using java, checking revokation and OCSP status

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate, ocsp

I am new to the world of PKI , certificates in general. I am writing a service which needs to validate a chain of certiticates.

The general approach taken is as follows

a)  Generate a List of certificates from the data sent

```
ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

CertPathValidatorResult certPathValidatorResult = null;
try {

  CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
  List<X509Certificate> x509Certificates =
      (List<X509Certificate>) certificateFactory.generateCertificates(byteArrayInputStream);

  CertPath certPath = certificateFactory.generateCertPath(x509Certificates);
```

2. Load the JDK keystore, with something like this
   //Load the JDK's cacerts keystore file
   String filename =
   System.getProperty("java.home")
   + "/lib/security/cacerts".replace('/', File.separatorChar);
   FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);
   KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
   String password = "changeit";
   keystore.load(is, password.toCharArray());
3. ```
   CertPathValidator certPathValidator = CertPathValidator.getInstance("PKIX");

   PKIXParameters pkixParameters = new PKIXParameters(keystore);
   //pkixParameters.setRevocationEnabled(false);

   PKIXParameters certPathValidatorResult = certPathValidator.validate(certPath, pkixParameters);
   ```
4. I am assuming if this is not a valid chain it would throw an exception. Would this validation check expired Certificates, Valid Public Key ?
5. also I need to be able to find the the OCSP staus of a certificate or check if it is revoked>? How can this be done using the Cryptography API
6. Is the use fo bouncy castle recommended over the API ? Does Bouncy castle have a way to check CRL and OCSP status of a certificate?

Thanks for all the pointers and help in advance. Appreciate it.

Best  Regards

Comment: PKIX validator checks expiry, and revocation by default. There is no general way to check a public key is validly generated, and even for specific algorithms it usually can't be done on the public key alone only the private key. PKIX validator can do OCSP, see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/java-pki-programmers-guide.html#GUID-E6E737DB-4000-4005-969E-BCD0238B1566 .

Answer (score 0):

1. It's correct, you can use CertificateFactory to load certificates chain.
2. If you want validate a chain of certiticates, you don't need a KeyStore. The certificates are validated with the certificate of autority who emit that certificate.
   For example:

```
ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(chain.getBytes());
CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
List<X509Certificate> x509Certificates = (List<X509Certificate>) certificateFactory.generateCertificates(byteArrayInputStream);
x509Certificates.get(1).verify(x509Certificates.get(0).getPublicKey());
```

3. In this case you can use it to validate a certificate if you don't know the root ca.
4. You can check the period with

```
x509Certificates.get(1).getNotBefore()
```

and

```
x509Certificates.get(1).getNotAfter()
```

5. Is important validate the status of certificate.
6. Yes BouncyCastle is great library for it.

Comment: `X509Certificate.verify` only verifies the signature on one cert; that, or even checking each cert in a chain, is only a small fraction of what is required to _validate_ the chain; see RFC5280 section 6. _That_ is what `CertPathValidator` is for.

Comment: Thanks @DarkVeider for those comments. Really appreciate it. A few more clarifications  List<X509Certificate> x509Certificates = (List<X509Certificate>) certificateFactory.generateCertificates(byteArrayInputStream);
x509Certificates.get(1).verify(x509Certificates.get(0).getPublicKey());  DOes this mean the first Certificate is always the root Certificate ?   When you say a KeyStore is not needed for verification, would the verify() be able to tell an untrusted certificate ?  It looks like there is no complete way to verify a certificate chain then, or am i missing something? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Doesn't that mean the first certificate is always the root certificate, it depends of the certificates order on the byte array. dave_Thompson has reason in his comment.

Comment: And yes verify () be able to tell an untrusted certificate if you know who emmit the certificate and then use the correct certificate to verify. CertPathValidator can help you to find the correct certificate and validate without know who emmited the certificate.